# android horizontal scrolling with buttons

Tags: android

Hi im wanting to create a function that allows the user to swipe left and right and a button slides in horizontally. for example there will be a big button on screen when you swipe it moves horizontally and another big button could anyone point me in the right direction as i have no idea where to start with it?

heres an example of what i'm looking for
[image]

Comment: post some code so anybody can help you.

Comment: Do you know this: http://viewpagerindicator.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use viewpager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

and when the current page changes (there is a listener to do this) you can change the circle images at the bottom to show the properly page.

:)

Comment: useful link http://viewpagerexample.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java